# how to pass samplebuffer of processSampleBuffer from app Extension to controller in ios

Tags: ios, webrtc, screensharing

struggling to pass ProcessSampleBuffers sample buffer from app extension to controller i have tried to pass buffers through delegate but its not working any answer regarding these will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using App Groups. Check [this article](https://agostini.tech/2017/08/13/sharing-data-between-applications-and-extensions-using-app-groups/) to understand how it works. This solution is based on BBPortal framework. I need to inform you, that this is not the best solution, because transferring of samplebuffers will depend on write/read speed of device flash memory. I've implemented this solution in my app and it was quite slow, so changed functionality to send samplebuffers on server because it is much more faster.

Comment: thanks for responding i cant transfer samplebuffers to server with rtmp url can you please add some snippets regarding transferring

Answer (score 0):

You can create a library/framework that manages both your app and your extension's IO. Then send buffers from your extension to your framework after processing them you can inform your container app. For example,

MyExtension.appex: Sends buffers to your common framework via delegation or KVO(More Expensive)

MyCommonFramework.framework: Receives the buffer and its type then renders with Core Image after its processed passed to Main App.

MyApp.app: Can hold a reference to CommanFramework's buffer processor classes, via delegation or KVO will receive the processed buffers or video/audio itself.

Comment: Do you have any example. AFAIK, the bridging framework will have separate instances for Extension and App.